xhtml2pdf not vertically centering text
The example below results in top aligned text, yet running with any other html+css editor results in centered text.
According to the docs, all tags used are supported.
"<div style='background-color: #022090; height: 60px; text-align: center;'><p style=' line-height: 60px; color: white'>My Title</p></div>"

vertical-align makes no difference
